# Changing the Uber Cadence Sleep time based on external (e.g. user) input

Tags: go, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Is there an example of a Cadence workflow changing the sleep duration based on external input?

The scenario I'm looking for is this: the workflow goes into sleep until time X but after the sleep starts but before it completes, there is an external trigger that causes time X to change to time Y. Y can either be later or earlier than X. It can even be earlier than "now", which should release the sleep immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code snippet for what you are looking for

```
func SampleTimerWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, timerDelay time.Duration) error 
{
    logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx)
    resetCh := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, "reset")

    timerFired := false
    delay := timerDelay
    for ;!timerFired; {
        selector := workflow.NewSelector(ctx)

        logger.Sugar().Infof("Setting up a timer to fire after: %v", delay)
        timerCancelCtx, cancelTimerHandler := workflow.WithCancel(ctx)
        timerFuture := workflow.NewTimer(timerCancelCtx, delay)
        selector.AddFuture(timerFuture, func(f workflow.Future) {
            logger.Info("Timer Fired.")
            timerFired = true
        })

        selector.AddReceive(resetCh, func(c workflow.Channel, more bool) {
            logger.Info("Reset signal received.")
            logger.Info("Cancel outstanding timer.")
            cancelTimerHandler()

            var t int
            c.Receive(ctx, &t)
            logger.Sugar().Infof("Reset delay: %v seconds", t)
            delay = time.Second * time.Duration(t)
        })

        logger.Info("Waiting for timer to fire.")
        selector.Select(ctx)
    }

    workflow.GetLogger(ctx).Info("Workflow completed.")
    return nil
}
```

Now you can send a signal to reset the timer to 10 seconds like below:

```
cadence-cli --domain <domain> wf signal -w <workflow_id>  --name reset --input 10
```

Comment: Hey Maxim, I'm wondering whats the purpose of `selector.AddReceive` and why we would need to use `selector.Select` near the end, but still within the for loop. I have SO question that reference this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665827/when-to-use-selector-addreceive-selector-select) 
Also confused by the `selector.AddReceive` because I'm looking at the timer example from `cadence-samples` [here](https://github.com/uber-common/cadence-samples/blob/master/cmd/samples/recipes/timer/workflow.go) and they use multiple `selector.Select` and no `selector.AddReceive`

Comment: I'm using signals as well, and when I send an ACCEPT signal, I would start the timer as below

A follow up to this,  I'm using 
```
if signal == ACCEPT, 
selector.AddFuture(timerFuture, func(f workflow.Future) {
      logger.Info("TIMER FIRED")
      timerFired = true
     })

if signal == CANCEL, 
 cancelTimerHandler()

```
timerFired is immediately set to true.