# Resetting Time for Uber Cadence Activity Expiration

Tags: cadence-workflow

This is a follow up to my question here
[Workflow Structure, Promotion Offer Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66622471/workflow-structure-promotion-offer-flow)

I am making a workflow that depends on an external service sending the cadence workflow signals.
In my current workflow, I am listening for signals such as "ACCEPT", "REJECT" "CANCEL".

This workflow also will receive an expiration date on creation. I would only want to start the timer once the user ACCEPTs the offer.

However, if in the middle of this workflow, we decide to extend the expiration date and give the user more time, I believe I would need to send a signal to the workflow, eg "reset". Here's a similar case
[Changing the Uber Cadence Sleep time based on external (e.g. user) input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840595/changing-the-uber-cadence-sleep-time-based-on-external-e-g-user-input)

My questions are:

1. is it possible to send additional data into the signal channel? eg a struct? if so.. how would I do that?
2. If it's not possible, my first thought is that I would need to create two channels. One for the user decisions (eg, ACCEPT, REJECT, CANCEL. As I do an switch case check on those strings) and I would need another channel that just accepts inputs as time, or the extended date. Would that be the correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. It's always recommended to use struct so that introducing more fields later is backward-compatible.
2. One channel is good enough for everything if using struct.