# When to use selector.AddReceive, selector.Select

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Would appreciate some clarification on when I should use `selector.AddReceive` and `selector.Select`. This might not be a Cadence problem, but perhaps I'm missing some knowledge with regards to Golang.

For `selector.Select` I think the basic idea is that we wait for the next output from a channel. Not entirely sure what `selector.AddRecieve` does.

For example, in the cadence examples, `local_activity` [link](https://github.com/uber-common/cadence-samples/blob/master/cmd/samples/recipes/localactivity/local_activity_workflow.go) and pasted below:

```
func signalHandlingWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context) error {
    logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx)
    ch := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, SignalName)
    for {
        var signal string
        if more := ch.Receive(ctx, &signal); !more {
            logger.Info("Signal channel closed")
            return cadence.NewCustomError("signal_channel_closed")
        }

        logger.Info("Signal received.", zap.String("signal", signal))

        if signal == "exit" {
            break
        }

        cwo := workflow.ChildWorkflowOptions{
            ExecutionStartToCloseTimeout: time.Minute,
            // TaskStartToCloseTimeout must be larger than all local activity execution time, because DecisionTask won't
            // return until all local activities completed.
            TaskStartToCloseTimeout: time.Second * 30,
        }
        childCtx := workflow.WithChildOptions(ctx, cwo)

        var processResult string
        err := workflow.ExecuteChildWorkflow(childCtx, processingWorkflow, signal).Get(childCtx, &processResult)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        logger.Sugar().Infof("Processed signal: %v, result: %v", signal, processResult)
    }

    return nil
}
```

We don't use any `selector.AddReceive`

But, in the example here, where it uses signal channels as well: [Changing the uber cadence sleeptime based on external input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840595/changing-the-uber-cadence-sleep-time-based-on-external-e-g-user-input)

I'll also paste the code here

```
func SampleTimerWorkflow(ctx workflow.Context, timerDelay time.Duration) error 
{
    logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx)
    resetCh := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, "reset")

    timerFired := false
    delay := timerDelay
    for ;!timerFired; {
        selector := workflow.NewSelector(ctx)

        logger.Sugar().Infof("Setting up a timer to fire after: %v", delay)
        timerCancelCtx, cancelTimerHandler := workflow.WithCancel(ctx)
        timerFuture := workflow.NewTimer(timerCancelCtx, delay)
        selector.AddFuture(timerFuture, func(f workflow.Future) {
            logger.Info("Timer Fired.")
            timerFired = true
        })

        selector.AddReceive(resetCh, func(c workflow.Channel, more bool) {
            logger.Info("Reset signal received.")
            logger.Info("Cancel outstanding timer.")
            cancelTimerHandler()

            var t int
            c.Receive(ctx, &t)
            logger.Sugar().Infof("Reset delay: %v seconds", t)
            delay = time.Second * time.Duration(t)
        })

        logger.Info("Waiting for timer to fire.")
        selector.Select(ctx)
    }

    workflow.GetLogger(ctx).Info("Workflow completed.")
    return nil
}
```

You can see there is `selector.AddReceive`, I'm not entirely sure what the purpose is or when I should use it.

I am trying to send a signal to my workflow that allows me to extend an expiration time. Meaning, it would delay the call of an `ExpirationActivity`

And when following this example (combined with my current code), as soon as I send the signal to reset, it seems that `timerFired` gets set immediately to true.

My current code is the below (I've taken out some irrelevant if statements), and previously, I was using only one instance of `selector.Select`, but somewhere my code wasn't acting properly.

```
func Workflow(ctx workflow.Context) (string, error) {
    // local state per bonus workflow
    bonusAcceptanceState := pending
    logger := workflow.GetLogger(ctx).Sugar()
    logger.Info("Bonus workflow started")
    timerCreated := false
    timerFired := false
    delay := timerDelay

    // To query state in Cadence GUI
    err := workflow.SetQueryHandler(ctx, "bonusAcceptanceState", func(input []byte) (string, error) {
        return bonusAcceptanceState, nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        logger.Info("SetQueryHandler failed: " + err.Error())
        return "", err
    }
    info := workflow.GetInfo(ctx)
    executionTimeout := time.Duration(info.ExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds) * time.Second
    // decisionTimeout := time.Duration(info.TaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds) * time.Second
    decisionTimeout := time.Duration(info.ExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds) * time.Second
    maxRetryTime := executionTimeout // retry for the entire time

    retryPolicy := &cadence.RetryPolicy{
        InitialInterval:          time.Second,
        BackoffCoefficient:       2,
        MaximumInterval:          executionTimeout,
        ExpirationInterval:       maxRetryTime,
        MaximumAttempts:          0, // unlimited, bound by maxRetryTime
        NonRetriableErrorReasons: []string{},
    }
    ao := workflow.ActivityOptions{
        TaskList:               taskList,
        ScheduleToStartTimeout: executionTimeout, // time until a task has to be picked up by a worker
        ScheduleToCloseTimeout: executionTimeout, // total execution timeout
        StartToCloseTimeout:    decisionTimeout,  // time that a worker can take to process a task
        RetryPolicy:            retryPolicy,
    }
    ctx = workflow.WithActivityOptions(ctx, ao)
    selector := workflow.NewSelector(ctx)
    timerCancelCtx, cancelTimerHandler := workflow.WithCancel(ctx)

    var signal *singalType

    for {
        signalChan := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, signalName)
        // resetCh := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, "reset")

        selector.AddReceive(signalChan, func(c workflow.Channel, more bool) {
            c.Receive(ctx, &signal)
        })

        selector.Select(ctx)

        if signal.Type == "exit" {
            return "", nil
        }

        // We can check the age and return an appropriate response
        if signal.Type == "ACCEPT" {
            if bonusAcceptanceState == pending {
                logger.Info("Bonus Accepted")
                bonusAcceptanceState = accepted

                var status string
                future := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, AcceptActivity)
                if err := future.Get(ctx, &status); err != nil {
                    logger.Errorw("Activity failed", "error", err)
                }
                // Start expiration timer
                if !timerCreated {
                    timerCreated = true
                    timerFuture := workflow.NewTimer(timerCancelCtx, delay)
                    selector.AddFuture(timerFuture, func(f workflow.Future) {
                        logger.Info("Timer Fired.")
                        timerFired = true
                    })
                }

            }
        }
        
        
        if signal.Type == "ROLLOVER_1X" && bonusAcceptanceState == accepted {
            var status string
            future := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, Rollover1x)
            if err := future.Get(ctx, &status); err != nil {
                logger.Errorw("Activity failed", "error", err)
            }
            selector.Select(ctx)
        }
        if signal.Type == "ROLLOVER_COMPLETE" && bonusAcceptanceState == accepted {
            var status string
            future := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, RolloverComplete)
            if err := future.Get(ctx, &status); err != nil {
                logger.Errorw("Activity failed", "error", err)
                return "", err
            }
            // Workflow is terminated on return result
            return status, nil
        }
        for; !timerFired && bonusAcceptanceState == accepted && signal.Type == "RESET" {
            cancelTimerHandler()

            i, err := strconv.Atoi(signal.Value)
            if err != nil {
                logger.Infow("error in converting")
            }

            logger.Infof("Reset delay: %v seconds", i)
            delay = time.Minute * time.Duration(i)
            timerFuture := workflow.NewTimer(timerCancelCtx, delay)
            selector.AddFuture(timerFuture, func(f workflow.Future) {
                logger.Info("Timer Fired.")
                timerFired = true
            })
            selector.Select(ctx)
        }
        if timerFired {
            var status string
            future := workflow.ExecuteActivity(ctx, ExpirationActivity)
            if err := future.Get(ctx, &status); err != nil {
                logger.Errorw("Activity failed", "error", err)
            }
            return status, nil
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

- You will only use `selector.AddReceive` when you need to let a selector to listen on a channel, like in your 2nd code snippet. If you only need to process signals from a channel directly without selector, then you don't need to use it.
- `selector.Select` is to let the code wait for some events to happen. Because  you don't want to use busy looping to wait.

### More details on when to use them

Essentially, this is exactly the same concept as [Golang select statement](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5). Golang select allows you to wait for timers and channels. Except that Golang doesn't have `selector.Select()` simply because it's baked into the language itself, but Cadence is a library.

So same as in golang, you don't have to use `select` statement to use timer or channel. You only need it when you have to write some code to listen on multiple sources of event.

For example, if you have two channels, you want to write some common logic to process these two channels, e.g increase a counter. This counter doesn't belong to any of the channels. It's a common counter. Then using a `selector` will looks nice.

```
chA := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, SignalNameA)
chB := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, SignalNameB)
counter := 0

selector.AddReceive(chA)
selector.AddReceive(chB)
For {
  selector.Select()
  counter += 1
}
```

The workflow code with selector looks very similar to this in Golang:

```golang
    counter := 0
    for {
        select {
        case _ := <- chA:
            counter += 1
        case _ := <- chB:
            counter += 1
        }
    }
```

Otherwise you may have to use two goroutines to listen on each channel, and do the counting. The golang code looks like this:

```golang
counter := 0
go func(){
   for{
      _ := <- chA
      counter += 1
   }
}()

go func(){
   for{
      _ := <- chB
      counter += 1
   }
}()
```

This could be a problem of race condition. Unless the counter is well implemented as thread-safe.

And in Cadence workflow code, it's something like this:

```
chA := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, SignalNameA)
chB := workflow.GetSignalChannel(ctx, SignalNameB)
counter := 0

Workflow.Go(ctx){
   for{
     chA.Receive(ctx,nil)
     counter +=1
   }
}

Workflow.Go(ctx){
   for{
     chB.Receive(ctx,nil)
     counter +=1
   }
}
```

However, there is no such race condition in Cadence, because Cadence's coroutine(started by`Workflow.Go()`) is not really concurrency. Both the two workflow code above should work perfectly.

But Cadence still provide this `selector` same as Golang, mostly because the 1st one is more natural to write code.

Answer (score 2):

check the future return result

```golang
selector.AddFuture(timerFuture, func(f workflow.Future) {
    err := f.Get(ctx, nil)
    if err == nil {
        logger.Info("Timer Fired.")
        timerFired = true
    }
})
```

ref: https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/0256258b905b677f2f38fcacfbda43398d236309/workflow/deterministic_wrappers.go#L128-L129

Comment: Sorry I understand that my question was long. To what point are you referring to in my question, that I should check the future return result. 
I wrote `And when following this example (combined with my current code), as soon as I send the signal to reset, it seems that timerFired gets set immediately to true.
`
Are you saying the reason it is set to true immediately, is because I've cancelled the timer? If I cancel the timer, shoudn't the action inside not take place anymore?

Comment: this is the documented behavior:
```
After timer is canceled, the returned Future become ready, and Future.Get() will return *CanceledError.
```
https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/0256258b905b677f2f38fcacfbda43398d236309/workflow/deterministic_wrappers.go#L128-L129

Comment: I am confused as to how the example here, we are able to reset the time without timerFired from breaking the loop. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840595/changing-the-uber-cadence-sleep-time-based-on-external-e-g-user-input

Comment: in the example, the selector has 2 cases assigned
* if timer future is ready (either timer fire or timer cancelled, you need to check the future result)
* if received a signal (which in the example will also cancel the timer)

when either one of the above future is ready, selector.Select(ctx) will be unblocked

Comment: I'm not exactly following. If the timer future is ready, the only thing it can do, is reassigned `timerFired` to `true`, it does not cancel the timer. 

Cancel timer can only be triggered when we send a `reset` signal. 

Do you think you can list the flow of that code snippet? Because I'm not sure where the selector.Select would be blocked, and wouldn't it be blocked. I can try first. 
1. worklow start
2. since `timerFired` is false, we are in the infinity for loop. 
3. And here, we create a selector using `workflow.NewSelector (also, should this be inside or outside the for loop

Comment: 4. we do `selector.addFuture` with the timer (and now its scheduled). 
5. User doesn't send any signals, so we are at `selector.Select(ctx)` waiting for timer to fire. 
6. User sends reset signal, which causes `CancelTimerHandler()` which then as you say, should reassigned `timerFired` to true. 
7. Now that timerFired is true, we break out of the loop and we should return nil. I Don't see how we can stay in the forloop and reset the time.